# Encrypt and decrypt string with metamask

Tags: metamask

I'd like to ask if there's a way to encrypt some content (e.g. a string) using Metamask.
I explain: let's say I've a DApp, I encript a string using the public_key of a user so that only this user, using his private_key (through metamask), can read the string.
Does metamask allow something like this?
Thank you

Comment: I think this question is relevant to yours: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/54962/using-ethereum-public-and-private-keys-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-message-metamask

Comment: Yeah, I saw it, thankyou. I was hoping for some news. It's strange they've not developed yet same kind of "asymmetric cryptography"

Comment: Maybe these could help? https://github.com/pubkey/eth-crypto

Comment: This particular example looks like what you're looking for: https://github.com/pubkey/eth-crypto/blob/master/tutorials/encrypted-message.md

Comment: I go through it but I think it's what i was looking for, thank you very much.